# Union and intersection of two languages

Tags: union, intersection, automaton

Given the language

L<sub>1</sub> = `{(i|l)p(f|g)n(f|h)m(f|i)r(l|m)p : n + m > r > 0, p >= 0}`

and

L<sub>2</sub> = `(f|g)*(h|i)+`

make an automaton for L<sub>1</sub> ∪ L<sub>2</sub> and (another one for) L<sub>1</sub> ∩ L<sub>2</sub>.

I know that the L<sub>1</sub> is a CFL and you need a PDA to parse it and I know that L<sub>2</sub> is a RL and a DFA is to be used.
 
My question is: how do you make the intersection (and the union)? That is, what is the actual language L<sub>3</sub> = L<sub>1</sub> ∩ L<sub>2</sub> on which you make the automaton and how do you compute it?

Answer (score 0):

Union is easy - if you have PDAs for two languages, a nondeterministic PDA that accepts the union can be had by introducing a new initial state with epsilon transitions to each of the initial states of the automata for your languages. The accepted language will be exactly whatever is accepted by either (or both) automata.

Intersection is a little more tricky. Now, you say you want an automaton - that could refer to any theoretical machine, including Turing machines or, equivalently, two-stack PDAs. If you are OK with creating a two-stack PDA then your task is straightforward. Use the Cartesian product machine construction used to construct a DFA for A and B given DFAs for A and B, and have each transition of the form ((a, b), w) -> (a', b') push a symbol (x, y) onto the stack iff (a, w)->a' pushes x onto A's stack and (b, w)->b' pushes y onto B's stack.

Of course, if you start with a DFA for the RL and perform the above construction you only need one stack and the resulting automaton is a PDA, not a two-stack PDA.